# Некорректный вывод текста из файла

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

Есть код который выводит в блок текст из файла:

```
setInterval(function() {
 $.get("text.txt", function(data) { 
  $("#content").text(data);
 });
}, 2000);
```

Файл text.txt:

```
пример1
пример2
```

Скрипт выводит текст в одну строку: пример1 пример2.
Как можно сделать чтобы текст выводился **строго** как в файле?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

как вариант

```
setInterval(function() {
    $.get("text.txt", function(data) { 
        $("#content").html('<pre>' + data + '</pre>');
    });
}, 2000);
```

Comment: Привет, XSS (хотя в случае автора возможно не критично)

Answer (score 2):

Попробуйте добавить css правило к элементу. в который выводите текст `white-space: pre-line`.

Либо применить js на подобии `string replacedText = row.Text.Replace("\n", "<br />");`